# Awk and discarding non-matching tokens in a string?

Tags: awk, sed, solaris, string, filter

I'm having trouble getting a string tool to provide what I need (due to my ignorance). I have a string based on CPU features. The string will [change as different processors offer different features](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/cryptest.sh#L835):

```
# Example from a modern Core i5 4th gen
SUNCC_CXXFLAGS="-D__SSE2__ -D__SSE3__ -D__SSSE3__ -D__SSE4_1__ -D__SSE4_2__ -D__AES__ -D__PCLMUL__ __AVX__ ..."
```

The string works great for Sun Studio 12.3 and above. For [Sun Studio 12.2 and below, I can only use SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1 and SSE4.2](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/228). AES and above defines [cause an obscure error](http://community.oracle.com/thread/1994545?start=0&tstart=0), so they must be filtered out of the flags.

Put another way I need the intersection of the two sets:

```
# Cannot use AES and above for SunCC 12.2
ALLOWED_CXXFLAGS="-D__SSE2__ -D__SSE3__ -D__SSSE3__ -D__SSE4_1__ -D__SSE4_2__"
# New processor, needs to be filtered due to old compiler
SUNCC_CXXFLAGS="-D__SSE2__ -D__SSE3__ -D__SSSE3__ -D__SSE4_1__ -D__SSE4_2__ -D__AES__ -D__PCLMUL__ __AVX__ ..."
```

I've seen a number of questions and answers with [awk matching (and non-matching) regexes and lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28885530/608639). But I need to filter based on tokens in a single line.

I tried the following, which does not produce expected results:

```
$ echo "-D__SSE2__ -D__SSE3__ -D__SSSE3__ -D__SSE4_1__ -D__SSE4_2__ -D__AES__ -D__PCLMUL__" | \
  nawk '!/(-D__SSE2__|-D__SSE3__|-D__SSSE3__)/'
$
```

Another twist: this is Solaris, so the tools don't have a lot of the options present in GNU tools. Its one of the reasons I tried awk instead of sed or grep.

How can I filter out the tokens that don't match my set of tokens?

Comment: Your expression prints non-matching *records* (lines) rather than non-matching substrings within those records - you could try `nawk '{gsub(/-D__SSE2__|-D__SSE3__|-D__SSSE3__/,"")}1'` but I would think it's just as likely that your version of sed supports a BRE of the form `sed 's/-D__SSE2__\|-D__SSE3__\|-D__SSSE3__//g'`

Comment: @John1024 - desired output only includes SSE. Modern processors will have all the SSE defines (plus additional defines which are causing problems). Older platforms, like Pentium Pro or Pentium II, may be missing SSE3 and SSSE3. In the case of older Pentiums, its conceivable the remaining `CXXFLAGS` only includes SSE2.

Comment: @jww Very good.  I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

To select only the SSE flags, try:

```
awk '/SSE/' ORS=' ' RS=' '
```

The key thing here is setting the record separators on input and output to a space.  That way, each option is accepted or rejected separately.

For example:

```
$ SUNCC_CXXFLAGS="-D__SSE2__ -D__SSE3__ -D__SSSE3__ -D__SSE4_1__ -D__SSE4_2__ -D__AES__ -D__PCLMUL__ ..."
$ newFLAGS="$(echo "$SUNCC_CXXFLAGS" | awk '/SSE/' ORS=' ' RS=' ')"
$ echo "$newFLAGS"
-D__SSE2__ -D__SSE3__ -D__SSSE3__ -D__SSE4_1__ -D__SSE4_2__
```

`SSE` appears to be a tight enough match here.  If it isn't, we can be more specific:

```
$ newFLAGS="$(echo "$SUNCC_CXXFLAGS" | awk '/^-D__(SSE2|SSE3|SSSE3|SSE4.1|SSE4.2)__/' ORS=' ' RS=' ')"
$ echo "$newFLAGS"
-D__SSE2__ -D__SSE3__ -D__SSSE3__ -D__SSE4_1__ -D__SSE4_2__
```

#### Alternative: excluding SSE and AES

```
$ echo "$SUNCC_CXXFLAGS" | nawk '!/SSE|AES/' ORS=' ' RS=' '
-D__PCLMUL__ ...
```

#### Keeping options that match `SSE` **or** `sse`

```
$ SUNCC_CXXFLAGS="-D__SSE2__ -D__SSE3__ -D__SSSE3__ -D__SSE4_1__ -D__SSE4_2__ -D__AES__ -D__PCLMUL__ -xarch=sse3"
$ newFLAGS="$(echo "$SUNCC_CXXFLAGS" | awk '/SSE|sse/' ORS=' ' RS=' ')"
$ echo "$newFLAGS"
-D__SSE2__ -D__SSE3__ -D__SSSE3__ -D__SSE4_1__ -D__SSE4_2__ -xarch=sse3
```

The change here is that we replaced the regex `/SSE/` with `/SSE|sse/`.  Because the vertical bar, `|`, means logical-or, this matches either `SSE` or `sse`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. It tested as expected, and was [checked in](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/fa758dbbd70a6acf568dfb79bf52328078455dcf).

Comment: Very good.  Glad it worked.

Comment: Sorry to dig up an old thread. Solaris is acting up again. We found we needed to add `-xarch` to fix another problem, which means we need to match a lowercase `sse` too. `echo "$newFLAGS"` should return `-D__SSE2__ -D__SSE3__ -D__SSSE3__ -D__SSE4_1__ -D__SSE4_2__ -xarch=ssse3`. I visited [3.8 Case Sensitivity in Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html#Case_002dsensitivity) of the manual, but its not quite clicking for me. Would you be able to modify to *match* lowercase, too (but preserve case on output)? Or do you want a new question?

Comment: @jww I just added a new section to the end of the answer that does what I think you are asking for.   (Because you are on Solaris, try to use `nawk` or                                   
better yet `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`  or `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` in place of Solaris' awk.)

Comment: @jww That was kind and generous of you!  I'm glad that the answer helped.